# unable to verify hash for node 'raspberrypi': hash does not match

Tags: raspberry-pi4, rancher, k3s

On a cluster of 2 RPI 4's I see this when it seems to setup the worker node. The master seems to be fine. I have connected only 2 RPIs now.
I think the network switch is fine but if this is a networking issue I may be missing something.

I use `ansible-playbook  site.yml -i inventory/rpi/hosts.ini`

> k3s_version: v1.23.4+k3s1

This error repeats.
But I see this.

```
kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config-berry-pi
 NAME        STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION 
raspberrypi   Ready    control-plane,master   4m41s   v1.23.4+k3s1
```

This is from the journal in the master pi.

```
pr 01 11:58:14 raspberrypi k3s[13742]: time="2022-04-01T11:58:14+01:00" level=error msg="unable to verify hash for node 'raspberrypi': hash does not match"
Apr 01 11:58:15 raspberrypi k3s[13742]: I0401 11:58:15.180204   13742 request.go:665] Waited for 1.053982859s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: POST:https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/serviceaccounts/coredns/token
Apr 01 11:58:19 raspberrypi k3s[13742]: time="2022-04-01T11:58:19+01:00" level=error msg="unable to verify hash for node 'raspberrypi': hash does not match"
Apr 01 11:58:24 raspberrypi k3s[13742]: time="2022-04-01T11:58:24+01:00" level=error msg="unable to verify hash for node 'raspberrypi': hash does not match"
Apr 01 11:58:29 raspberrypi k3s[13742]: time="2022-04-01T11:58:29+01:00" level=error msg="unable to verify hash for node 'raspberrypi': hash does not match"
Apr 01 11:58:34 raspberrypi k3s[13742]: time="2022-04-01T11:58:34+01:00" level=error msg="unable to verify hash for node 'raspberrypi': hash does not match"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to proceed by executing on each worker node.

```
sudo curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN="K10e9d200a500ad44ba0072af9ea9f38d19a40cfc4cfd96d753d01466c618007f8e::server:bb58186ddf5f34800004affa48c44a12" K3S_URL="https://192.168.1.29:6443" K3S_NODE_NAME="rpiworker1" sh -
```

This token is obtained from the k3s server.

```
sudo cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/token
K10e9d200a500ad44ba0072af9ea9f38d19a40cfc4cfd96d753d01466c618007f8e::server:bb58186ddf5f34800004affa48c44a12
```

The `ansible-playbook` installed the `master` but it seemed to be stuck after that. I did not understand the reason for that error in the log though.